# Passing values using cookies

Tags: java, jsp, cookies

in my `servlet.java` I've declared a cookie,

```
String loc = "Some random data";
Cookie thecookie = new Cookie("thecookie", loc);
response.addCookie(thecookie);
```

Later after performing some file upload stuff I am setting a value to this cookie again,

```
fileTxt = FileUtils.readFileToString(uploadedFile);
thecookie.setValue(fileTxt);

RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("thejsppage.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Now in my jsp page as redirected above,

```
<%
  Cookie[] my = request.getCookies();
  for(int i=0;i<my.length;i++){
  String filetext = my[i].getValue().toString();
 }
%>

<div id="editor"><%=filetext %></div>
```

But this is returning a garbage value, what is my mistake?

How do I pass values using cookies?

I do not want to use `request.setAttribute("name", value);` method.

Comment: What kind of garbage? Unrelated to the contents of the file? And how large is the file? You cannot set very much data to a cookie.

Comment: The file consists of only a few lines..max 4-5 lines and I am getting something like this `6695A3FB6519959B0959CD6F25B886B5`

Comment: If you aren't going to access the cookie in Javascript client side, why use cookies rather than the session?

Comment: And why would you ever store a file in a cookie?

Comment: BY using session I am getting the problem of multi tab operation of same browser and the session remains the same.

Comment: You'll get that same problem with cookies.  Use request attributes.

Comment: Yes, I've tried using `request.setattributes` stuff but the problem is that I loose data whenever page is refreshed during a `request-response` period

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my above question,

I've changed

```
<%
  Cookie[] my = request.getCookies();
  for(int i=0;i<my.length;i++){
  String filetext = my[i].getValue().toString();
 }
%>

<div id="editor"><%=filetext %></div>
```

to

```
<%
  Cookie[] my = request.getCookies();
  for(int i=0;i<my.length;i++){
  if(my.getName()=="thecookie"){
  String filetext = my[i].getValue().toString();
   }
  }
%>

<div id="editor"><%=filetext %></div>
```

and now I am able to get the desired value.